# Resources are missing in apk

Tags: android, react-native, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

I'm trying to add a .wav file to my React Native app and having a problem with Android implementation.
The file keeps getting removed from the build (its' missing in the res/raw folder when I'm unzipping the apk).

Folder structure:

[image]

keep.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:keep="@raw/push_notification_sound"
/>
```

Both shrinking and minifying are disabled in `build.gradle` for all build types:

```
minifyEnabled false
shrinkResources false
```

Any ideas what might be the reason behind this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad should have put the assets into `android/app/src/main/res/raw/`

Comment: Can you improve your answer so you can help others you need more explanation? in your question the push_notification_sound.wav it is already in your res/raw?